# Resize SKSpriteNodes with their SKPhysicsBody in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, resize, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skaction

I was wondering what the appropriate way was to resize an SKSpriteNode WITH its SKPhysicalBody in SpriteKit. At first I thought I could use SKActions to do resizeToX/Y and that would work. I tried doing this like:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction resizeToY:whateverFloat completion:^{
   SKPhysicalBody *newBody = [SKPhysicalBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spriteNode.size];
   spriteNode.physicalBody = newBody;
}];
```

NOTE : I typed this from memory, its not the exact code, so please ignore syntax errors. I also tried moving around the variables just in case to see what happens. For example, I tried instantiating newBody outside the completion block. I tried assigning the newBody outside the completion block. I tried to update the categoryBitMask and all the same contactBitMasks again. Nothing works.

The closest I got it to working was when I didn't add a new physicalBody, the SKSpriteNode would resize, but its physicalBody would stay the same. If I add a new physicalBody, the whole SKSpriteNode disappears. I don't understand.

After searching online for a solution using SKAction, I found many different threads saying "SKActions don't work well with physics. Avoid mixing them." If I have to avoid mixing them, then how do I grow and shrink an SKSpriteNode the correct way and update its physical body while getting rid of its old one? The physics and collision logic from SpriteKits physics stuff is very important in my game.

Comment: It's the move & rotate actions you shouldn't use with physics. The other actions don't influence physics at all, ie changing scale does not change the scale of a physics body (enable physics debug drawing). Box2D used by SK doesn't support scaling physics bodies, and no physics engine I know supports this natively because there's a host of problems associated with it. What you can do is to remove the existing body, create a new one, and do so every update. Which is a hack-ish workaround, and physics behavior will be anything but what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But thats what Im doing right now. I make a new SKPhysicalBody and assign it to the sprite after it completes resizing itself. Do I need to manually remove the old physical body? Because whenbI assign a new physicalBody my spritenode just disappears.

Comment: The disappearing may be due to the body now being in a collision, or triggering a contact delegate that removes the sprite. It could literally be anything, but very unlikely that it's the mere act of assigning a new physicsBody.